# Update com JOIN no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, script

Estou fazendo um update para a tabela A a qual receberá valores da Tabela B

conforme `a.codigo = B.folha`
Ao rodar a rotina abaixo, fica lento e nada acontece por um bom tempo. São 500.000 linhas. É normal ou tenho que esperar ou o script está errado... nao sei o que fazer na rotina
na realidade tenho que trazer informações de B para A conforme a condicao.

```
UPDATE escrituras t1 INNER JOIN 
       imovel t2 ON t2.LIVRO = t1.CODIGO
   SET  
         t1.TipoImovelDescr = t2.DESCRICAO;
            a.RUA            =  b.RUA;
            a.BAIRRO      =  b.BAIRRO,
            a.MUNICIPIO = b.CIDADE,
            a.UF               = b.ESTADO
```

Comment: O que é `a` e `b`? Não está definido na *query*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A consulta têm alguns erros de de sintaxe como os alias `a` e `b` um ponto e virgula sobrando na primeira linha depois do set, sua consulta deve ficar dessa forma.

```
UPDATE escrituras t1 INNER JOIN 
       imovel t2 ON t2.LIVRO = t1.CODIGO
   SET  
      t1.TipoImovelDescr = t2.DESCRICAO,
      t1.RUA = t2.RUA,
      t1.BAIRRO =  t2.BAIRRO,
      t1.MUNICIPIO = t2.CIDADE,
      t1.UF = t2.ESTADO
```

Talvez o problema seja a falta de um `WHERE` alguns bancos cancelam essas instruções update/delete pois isso pode causar um seria estrago, imagine atualizar as descrições/categorias de todos os produtos para `sal/condimentos`. No mysql você pode ativar isso adicionando essa linha antes da sua consulta principal:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Comment: Ja estou rodando o script rray.muito obrigado até o momento..

Comment: Qual era o problema o where?

Comment: acredito que nao rray.